# Почему неправильный ответ может набрать много плюсов, а мой правильный - нет?

Tags: обсуждение

Последнее время у меня сложилось впечатление что на моей УЗ SO теневой бан, активности с моими ответами практически не происходит, но это как следствие вопроса, нежели сам вопрос.

Недавно оставлял ответ на вопрос:

> [Регулярное выражение: пять цифр, не все одинаковые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1497035)

Который стал достаточно популярным среди отвечающих, но с самым высоким рейтингом и отмеченным как верный находится ответ не подходящий под условие указанное в вопросе:

> должны проходить 5 цифр, но не одинаковые подряд. Например, 12345, 223341,44441, но не 00000, 11111 и т.д.

В чем причина такого поведения участников сообщества, голосование за ответы проходит по принципу - чем выше рейтинг, тем лучше ответ?
Возможно я заблуждаюсь и это во мне какая-то "гиена" ноет о не справедливости, а мои ответы являются не качественными и не стоят внимания? Хотелось бы понять что конкретно нравится людям в ответе с наивысшим рейтингом?
Ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1497078/485997

---

Сразу хочу уведомить, что к отвечающим, голосующим с моей стороны нет никаких упреков, мне интересно мнение сообщества, что мне нужно исправить в своих ответах, что бы хоть немного приносить пользу.

Comment: Одна из причин, тот факт что автор принял этот ответ

Comment: Вижу у вас тут два вопроса - "Почему неправильные ответы плюсуют" и "Почему мои ответы не плюсуют". Уточните, о чем же вы все же спрашиваете?

Comment: @Kromster, «мои ответы не плюсуют» является причиной появления вопроса «почему плюсуют не совсем верные ответы». Т.е. интересен подход сообщества, неужели рейтинг отвечающего играет важную роль. Изначально вопрос задан не корректно, без попыток самостоятельно решить его, обычно такие вопросы минусуются, хотя раньше я мог ответить на такой и получить в лучшем случает один голос. Пока для меня непонятна природа такого интереса. Со стороны пытаюсь оценить этот вопрос сейчас и да, больше походит на «нытье»

Comment: Вопрос по ссылке плохой, тут с вами согласен. Поменял вашему вопросу название тут, проверьте плиз, правильно ли?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На что обратить внимание:

- По умолчанию, ответы на вопрос располагаются по рейтингу (чем больше, тем выше). То есть тут уже идет некоторая дискриминация (не факт что плохая).
- В общем случае, если у вопроса уже есть 2-4 ответа с достаточным количеством плюсов и без шумных выяснений в комментариях (а тем более один с галкой принятого) - мало кто будет сомневаться в их правильности и искать альтернативы.
- Другим критерием может быть объемность/понятность ответов. Если есть и большие и короткие, освещающие разные подходы к решению, то опять же мало резона скроллить вниз.
- Дополнительным моментом может быть популярность вопроса - если это ребус-однодневка, то он получит свои 15 минут славы и сгинет. Никто в нем повторно нуждаться не станет. В то же время, бывают вопросы поймавшие какую-то волну, на которые каждый месяц по +1000 визитов - по ним поток внимания больше и часть этого внимания перепадет и на поздние ответы.
- Рейтинг дающего ответ также играет заметную роль. Если ответ дает участник с 200к репутации, то "еще один правильный ответ от опытного мастера!", а если 120 репутации, то "ну может он и прав, а может и нет ..".

Итого получается, что дав поздний ответ, вы несколько опоздали на праздник раздачи "плюсов" (по многим критериям).